# Resin Restarts when class files or Servlets are uploaded

Tags: jsp, dynamic, webserver, restart, resin

When we upload a .class file or a servlet to the server, the webserver restarts. This does not happen when we upload a JSP. Is there a way to configure Resin so that it dynamically loads the class without restarting the web server?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, Resin is the only servlet engine that can reload classes if they change. To do that, you need to use the [`<compiling-loader>`](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/env-tags.xtp#compiling-loader) that *configures an auto-compiling WEB-INF/classes-style class loader*. *This compiling-loader will automatically compile Java code into .class files loading them.*

Below, an example of `WEB-INF/web-resin.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin">
  <prologue>
    <class-loader>
      <compiling-loader path="WEB-INF/classes"
                        source="WEB-INF/src"/>
    </class-loader>
  </prologue>
</web-app>
```

My understanding is that Resin will check each and every **source** file and, if they have changed from the .class time/date/size in `WEB-INF/classes`, then Resin unloads the current class from the JVM, recompiles the .java file, then reloads that class.